# JetBrains Rider puts global.json by default which cannot be resolved

Tags: c#, json, .net

Once I create a project in JetBrains Rider, it puts global.json by default and it is unable to resolve the .NET SDK version.

Why?

> Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets(127, 5): [NETSDK1141] Unable to resolve the .NET SDK version as specified in the global.json located at C:\Users\user\Desktop\Nick Chapsas Elfocrash\basic-sources-master\ASPNETCoreTutorials\ResultVideo.Api\global.json.

```cs
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "6.0.0",
    "rollForward": "latestMinor",
    "allowPrerelease": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look up the error code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/sdk-errors/netsdk1141

You most likely don't have .NET 6.0 SDK installed.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/c7dwqzA.png, oh I see, I have the preview versions.

Comment: @nop .NET 5 reached End Of Life 6 months ago